# Is there a REST interface for accessing DSE/DataStax graph

Tags: graph, datastax, titan, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

Is there a REST interface for accessing DSE/DataStax graph? I read all available documents but could not find anything. Any pointers to this will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DSE Graph does not have a REST API, despite packaging Gremlin Server. DSE embeds Gremlin Server as an option but does so in a custom manner that overrides the `channelizer` setting in the YAML file. So even if you add the TinkerPop `HttpChannelizer`, the DSE based channelizer will take over.

The preferred method to connect to DSE Graph is with the available drivers, either those provided by the TinkerPop community for Gremlin SErver or the DataStax drivers over native protocol.